# CURL --upload-file in PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm scratching my head around a stuff from last few hours, basically I wanna convert this chunk of code to PHP codes

```
  curl -X POST \
    'http://api.testwyre.com/v3/accounts/AC-XXXANREWUNJ/individualGovernmentId?documentType=DRIVING_LICENSE&documentSubType=FRONT&timestamp=1426252182534' \
    --upload-file '/Users/user/passport.pdf' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/pdf' \
    -H 'X-Api-Signature: XXXX' \
    -H 'X-Api-Key: XXXX'
```

My only problem is::

> How to use **--upload-file** as **POST Request** in **PHP Curl** ?

Please anyone help me in converting above code to PHP

Comment: Maybe https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ ?

Comment: @Syscall tried already but its also ignoring the `--upload-file` part